# Pandas dataframes Python to find % distribution using a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this, where I need to find the % of each item based on date,

```
Grade   Count   Date    
A+      303    8/7/2020 
B+      35     8/7/2020 
A+      450    8/7/2017 
B+      23     8/7/2017
```

I want need find the Percentage distribution of each row based on date column as below,

```
Grade   Count   Date    %Change
A+      303    8/7/2020 89.65
B+      35     8/7/2020 10.35

A+      450    8/7/2017 95.14
B+      23     8/7/2017  4.86
```

I used groupby() and sum() but couldn't quite get to what I want.

*P.S - Apologize for the misinterpretation of HTML code. I was trying to format the table using HTML, but it came out as my query was around HTML code, which is not.*

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Can you revise the question to make it more clear?

Comment: I used the HTML code to format the table, which came out bad and completely digressed from my intent of raising the question. I have corrected it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# first：you could find the sum of count groupby date
df_ = df.groupby(by='Date')['Count'].sum()
date_2_count = df_.to_dict()
# then: you could calculate the %change by date_2_count
df['%Change'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Count']*100/date_2_count[x['Date']], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking " why are you converting the dataframe to dictionary?" May be a dumb question, but it's quite late into the night and I am not thinking straight..... "sigh!!!!"

Comment: I think that the "date_2_count" is a mapping from "Date" to the sum of "Count". Maybe it is easy to understand (￣▽￣)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use 100% pandas methods, so it gets faster.

```
df_date_sum = df.groupby(by='Date') \
    .agg({'Count': 'sum'}) \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename(columns={'Count': 'Total'})
df = df.merge(df_date_sum, how='left', on='Date')
df['%Change'] = (df['Count']/df['Total'])*100
```